# Python string manipulation using xrange

Tags: python, string

What is faster way to manipulate `myInput` string in order to have `myOutput` string?

```
myInput  = "1,3-5,7"

myOutput = "1,3,4,5,7"
```

Comment: Faster than what? Please show that you at least tried.

Comment: What does "x-y" mean ? All numbers between x and y ?

Comment: this is a near duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481192/pythonic-format-for-indices whichs answer is for `"1,3-5,7"` into `[1,3,4,5,7]` doing `','.join(answer(v))` to that gives the answer for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.sub( 
      "(\d+)-(\d+)" ,        
      lambda x : ",".join( map( str , range( int(x.group(1)) , int( x.group(2) ) +1 ) )) , 
      "1,3-5,7" )
```

You can get "1,3,4,5,7"

Answer (score 1):

i remember a question on SO that turned [1,3,4,5,7] into "1,3-5,7" but i don't remember which

this is the opposite problem:

```
def expand(s): 
    return ','.join(sum([v if len(v)==1 else map(str, apply(lambda a,b: range(a,b+1), map(int, v))) for v in [p.split('-') for p in s.split(',')]],[]))

print expand("1,3-5,7")
```

prints:

```
1,3,4,5,7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def expand(s):
...   for p in s.split(","):
...     r = p.split("-")
...     if len(r) == 1:
...       yield str(r[0])
...     else:
...       for i in range(int(r[0]), int(r[1]) + 1):
...         yield str(i)
... 
>>> ",".join(expand("1,3-5,7"))
'1,3,4,5,7'
>>> ",".join(expand("1-5,8,10,13-19"))
'1,2,3,4,5,8,10,13,14,15,16,17,18,19'
```

Obviously this will fail in various interesting ways if the input does not conform to the assumptions (letters, reverse sequences, etc.), and it does not work with negative numbers.